# Got TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfMiddleware.php line 16 laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am making an ecommerce web application using Laravel 5.

Now I am stuck at the payment integration. I am using `CCAvenue` as my payment integration, but there is no support provided from the ccavenue itself for laravel framework.

So, after a bit of research, I got this package called [Indipay](https://github.com/softon/indipay). This package works completely fine. However, I get `TokenMismatchException`. Though the transaction is successful and I do get the notification of the payment being received.

Check the below image:

[image]

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/store/proceed-to-checkout', 'CheckoutController@proceedToCheckout');
Route::get('/store/thank-you', 'PagesController@getThankYou');
```

**CheckoutController.php**

```
public function proceedToCheckout(Request $request)
{
    $orderCode = Order::latest()->limit(1)->first();
    $newOrderCode = ($orderCode) ? ++$orderCode->order_code : 'ORD-000000001';

    $parameters = [
        'merchant_id' => $request->get('merchant_id'),
        'currency' => $request->get('currency'),
        'redirect_url' => $request->get('redirect_url'),
        'cancel_url' => $request->get('cancel_url'),
        'language' => 'EN',
        'order_id' => $newOrderCode,
        'actionId' => $request->get('actionID'),
        'TxnType' => $request->get('TxnType'),
        'amount' => $request->get('amount'),
        'tid' => time().rand(111,999)
    ];

    return Indipay::purchase($parameters);
}
```

**PagesController.php**

```
public function getThankYou(Request $request)
{
    $ordCode = Session::get('ordCode');

    $response = Indipay::response($request);

    dd($response);

    //return view('version-seven.pages.thank_you', compact('ordCode'));
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        //'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfMiddleware',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthentication',
    ];

}
```

What could be the possible issue ? Can anybody help me out with this ??

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Ok...I was in a situation like this. Disabling the `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` is not a good solution.
The best way to do this, disable the URL's particularly for those need the token.Like this:

```
 protected $except = [
    'transaction-failed/*',
    'transaction-successful/*',
    'payment-notification/*',

];
```

**Note: do not forget to add a '/*' at the end of the URL.**

Comment: 6 hours of struggle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add csrf token in your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

My situation is also same , I am developing ecommerce website & using Payubiz payment gateway in Laravel 5.1.

I was also getting the same error message of token mismatch, Instead of disabling CSRF I added this line to my form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
```

This perfectly workes for me without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented CCAvenue with Laravel for quite a few times. This is an approach issue. You actually redirect the user to third party site (in this case CCAvenue) and it will redirect it to your application's form as a POST request. Your csrf token middleware will block your route as there is no token. There are three solutions :

1. **Upgrade to 5.1** - You might consider the option of upgrading to 5.1 as it will let you have the possibility to disable middleware for routes. Then you might disable csrf token for response route and it will work like a charm. This is recommended soution as it is very easy to migrate to 5.1 (about 10-15 minutes of time is required) and you will have much more components of 5.1 to leverage in your app
2. Disable csrf token middleware for all your post routes and this will work.
3. Pass on your csrf token in parameter variable of CCAvenue (Not recommended)

Answer (score -1):

You have a more simple way to do this. It is described in Laravel Documentation.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

You can easily exclude some links from token middleware.

Comment: A workaround might be better posted as a comment instead of an anwser.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for tips guys. I'm sorry, i'm new on this plateform.